# Material assigning not working

Tags: materials, color

[image]Hi i would like to change the color of the head of my maggots but its not changing even i assigning the new material colored yellow why ? 
[image]

new problem encountered

when i assign a new color material to the head of my maggot it change but when i unselected the head then i select in any other parts of my maggots . the head color turn back to its previous color but if when i selecting the head it has the color brown but when i unselect it backs to color blue

Answer (score 5):

The Viewport color of your object and the diffuse color of your material are separate things in blender.
You can set the viewport color of your material separately.

Expand the Settings tab under your Material settings and change the viewport color:

[image]

A quick side note: the viewport color doesn't affect the render result in any way. its primary function is to structure your scene.

Answer (score 3):

Select all the faces you want to be a different material, I use Ctrl+L to quickly select larger groups of connected faces, Click the assign button just beneath the material list, and then **change the display method to Material** to see the colors as they are set on the various materials.

[image]

2.8 workbench some features coming out to differentiate objects with color ids which looks great!

Comment: Hi i found a new problem every time i assign a new color material into the head it change but after i click the other part of my character like the body the head color turn back to the previous color ?? why